# Java : Hashcode of a Class A containing a Class B which contains A

Tags: java

I have a problem while implementing the hashcode function in my classes. As explained in the title, I have two classes:

- The class A represents a school test, and so, it contains several attribute (i.e subject, mark, and an instance of the class representing the student who took the test).
- The class B is as you can guess, the one representing the student. It has some attributes (i.e name, address, age, etc) AND an ArrayList containing multiple A class instance (the student can take many tests).

There comes my problem, I am asked to implement the hashcode functions in both classes. The hashcode I use is the one i've been taught, which is adding the hashcode of every attributes, multiplied by an integer depending of it's type(i.e multiply by 31 for Strings, 17 for int, 13 for Objects, etc).

But if i call the hashcode of the A class, then the hashcode of the B class is called, and then it calls back the hashcode of A class.

How do I get rid of this loop? I thought of getting rid of the hashcode call of the student class (A) hashcode in the test class (B). But are there any other option? It's my first attempt to get help, I hope I didnt make it to hard to understand.

Comment: "The hashcode I use is the one i've been taught, which is adding the hashcode of every attributes" => This is what you should overthink again. Maybe the background of this exercise is exactly that. When do two student objects mean the _same_ student (aka they are equal)? The same question must be asked for the class test objects. In general: What attributes make up the _identity_ of an object?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of code that you have written?

Comment: Note that the hashcode should be immutable for the lifetime of the object, otherwise all sorts of bad things can happen (e.g.you won't be able to find the object in a HashSet). Is this true for all of your attributes? Are there some attributes that somehow make uo the "identity" of your object (and are thus immutable)?

Comment: My bad, thought the definition of the hashcode i was given was correct, but now knowing that the hashcode shouldn't change during the object's lifetimee, it looks obvious that the ArrayList should not participate in the hashcode of the student. Thought two objects with the same hashcode meant they were equals, but it's more like two objects which are equal must have the same hashcode. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @Wildrat "two objects which are equal must have the same hashcode" Have look at the general contract documented in the [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) and the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to avoid your problem is to change the abstraction. The class that represents a school test ("class A") doesn't have to hold a reference of the student instance ("class B"). Instead, it can hold some identifier of that student (some unique property of the student).

Another way: I believe it makes sense to say that a student is not defined by the tests that they take. This means that two student instances that are equal in all properties except of the list of tests are referring to the same student. This implies that the list of tests should not participate in the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods.

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong thinking the problem was coming from the test hashcode. It makes more sense to change the student one.